# In Django views, how do I render get requests

Tags: python, django

In Django I am writing a view which processes a GET request from a page index.html and renders the request to another page match_listing.html. The page index.html has a number of checkboxes to modify the data displayed on match_listing.html.

At the moment my code interrogates the GET request to determine the value of each of the checkboxes and then adds these to the context rendered to the page match_listing. This approach is clearly "unpythonic" and unsatisfactory. Can anyone suggest how I might be able to improve my code?

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Pl1516
from .parse import parse_load


def index(request):
    if not request.GET.get('hometeam'):
        return render(request, 'main/index.html')
    else:
        hometeam_filter = request.GET.get('hometeam')
        ht_filter = request.GET.get('HT')
        htr_filter = request.GET.get('HTR')
        ftr_filter = request.GET.get('FTR')
        matches = Pl1516.objects.filter(hometeam=hometeam_filter)
        if matches.count() < 19:
            parse_load(hometeam_filter)
        context_dict = {'ht_filter': ht_filter,  'ftr_filter':     htr_filter,           'htr_filter': htr_filter,  'matches' : matches}
        return render(request, 'main/match_listings.html', context_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

There may very well be a better way to do this, but I used a dictionary comprehension in a similar instance to do it in one go:

```
safe_get_params = { k: v for k, v in request.GET.items() if k in ['HT', 'HTR', 'FTR'] }
```

Since it looks like you are modifying the keys to be lower with '_filter' appended, you can modify as follows if necessary:

```
context_dict = { (k.lower() + '_filter'): v for k, v in request.GET.items() if k in ['HT', 'HTR', 'FTR'] }
```

After, you can then add the `matches` key:

```
context_dict['matches'] = matches
```

And you are on your merry way.

Comment: Hi Brian, Many thanks for your swift and concise response. Your suggestion worked straight out of the box and has given my code a much more pythonic sheen! This was my first posting on stackoverflow - a very encouraging response!

Comment: @DavidG Glad it helped. If you found this useful, feel free to upvote/accept for posterity

Answer (score 0):

So, you have two views that:

1. no further information > `index.html`
2. hometeam! > `match_listings.html`

This looks like regular URL routing to me.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^ht-(?P<hometeam>\w+)/$', views.MatchListView.as_view(), name='match_list'),
]
```

On the client side, instead of appending the query string, call instead the other URL. Or, if you still need to support the query string url:

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'main/index.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        hometeam = request.GET.get('hometeam', None)
        if hometeam:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('match_list', kwargs={'hometeam': hometeam}, permanent=True)
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

class MatchListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'main/match_listings.html'
    model = Pl1516
    # paginate_by = 20
    context_object_name = matches

    def get_queryset(self, queryset=None):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        hometeam = self.kwargs['hometeam']
        qs = qs.filter(hometeam=hometeam_filter)
        if qs.count() < 19:
            # is this pagination? what is this doing?
            parse_load(hometeam_filter)
        return qs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx.update({
            'ht_filter': self.request.GET.get('HT', None),
            'ftr_filter': self.request.GET.get('FTR', None),
            'htr_filter': self.request.GET.get('HTR', None)
        })
        return ctx
```

If `parse_load` really does pagination, consider using Django's in built pagination (you should make use of Django whenever you can).

There are loads of goodies in the Generic Views, imho, that might not be so evident at first. Things like returning 404 automatically when URL variables have no DB entry, pagination etc.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#using-singleobjectmixin-with-listview